# VSCode SonarQube support for Visual Studio Code Error 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, sonarqube

I am using  SonarQube support for Visual Studio Code on my VSCode to connect SonarQube server.

**Here is my Global config global.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silverbulleters/sonarqube-inject-vsc/master/schemas/global.json",
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": "localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9000/",
            "token": "0922636ce9de8248816fc2f8a89369a56788a64e"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my sonarlint.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silverbulleters/sonarqube-inject-vsc/master/schemas/sonarlint.json",
    "serverId": "localhost",
    "projectKey": "guru.springframework:springmvc"
}
```

And here is my error:

```
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 438419:07:17.704s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error executing SonarLint
ERROR: Error 400 on http://localhost:9000/api/components/tree.protobuf?qualifiers=BRC&baseComponentKey=guru.springframework%3Aspringmvc&ps=500&p=1: The 'component' parameter is missing
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarLint with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarLint using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Anyone can help how to solve this issue?
Any help could be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer, the problem is the VScode Plugin I use is not supporting Sonarqube 8.

Down grade to the version 7 solved the problem.